Syntax for using math.js in typescript file
I am writing an office 365 addin using typescript. I am trying to use functions from math.js. In my home.html head tag, I have the line:
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>

I test that I can use mathjs in this file through:
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(math.sqrt(-4).toString()) // 2i
</script>

which outputs 2i to the console as expected. I have another typescript file where I want to use math.erf. Here, it does not recognize math.
I have tried changing math.erf to erf but then it does not recognize erf.
I have tried:
import { erf } from 'mathjs'

as the first line of the file. This breaks the file so functions in the file are not recognized elsewhere.
I have tried:
const math = require('mathjs');

inside my function. I get a runtime error that require is not defined.
I have added:
  "dependencies": {"mathjs": "13.2.0"},

to my package.json file. I am not sure if this is necessary.

This seems like an issue with how the dependency is bundled into your runtime. If you are using the <script>-tag to load the JavaScript into your HTML, make sure it is in every HTML page which is being rendered.
